# How to use OR for observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I have two observables:

```
this.one$ = this.httpClient.get<any>();
this.tow$ = this.httpClient.get<any>();
```

I need to get third observable as result by condition:

```
if (url == "one) {
    this.result$ = this.one$;
} else if (url == "two") {
    this.result$ = this.two$;
}
```

Using in template:

```
{{ result | async }}
```

How to do this more elegant using Rxjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) conditional function. Try the following

```js
import { iif } from 'rxjs';

this.result$ = iif(() => url === "one", this.one$, this.two$);
```

From docs:

> Decides at subscription time which Observable will actually be
>   subscribed.

So if you were to subscribe in the controller (instead of using `async` pipe), you could dynamically change the condition before subscription.

```js
url: string;
this.result$ = iif(() => url === "one", this.one$, this.two$);

url = 'one';
this.result$.subscribe(...);      // <-- this.one$;

url = 'two'
this.result$.subscribe(...);      // <-- this.two$;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, I see two different solutions:

The first one is zipping them and return one of them in a `pipe`:

```js
const url = 'one';
const first$ = of('one');
const two$ = of('two');

zip(first, two).pipe(
  map(data => {
    if(url === 'one') {
      return data[0];
    } else {
      return data[1];
    }
  })
).subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

This is not the best solution for your problem but it can be useful sometimes.

Otherwise, you can use `iif` and you can use like this:

```js
result$ = iif(() => url === "one", one$, two$);
```